# One field for two purposes

Tags: database, database-design

Suppose a table has a field named the CalcType;

If the calculation type is a YEAR, the year value must be stored.

If the calculation type is a PERCENTAGE, the percent value must be stored.

Is it correct (in database design) to use one field for two purposes(Two different natures) for the calculation value? Or there should be one field for each type of calculation?

Comment: It might be better to ask "drawn from two different domains" rather than "for two different purposes", or "two different natures".  This depends on what you are really trying to find out.  Using the same data for more than one purpose is at the heart of what made databases a good idea about 50 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
Technically, you could - but it is strongly not advised. You could read into [Database normalisations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Satisfying_3NF)(up until 3 is commonly used).

---

You make things more complicated to work with. In case this column ever becomes a factor for a query, you have to differ each row which value it actually represents.

Technically, it does not make much sense - assuming you got fractions with percentage and basically an int or date-type for a year. You could use the sign-bit to differ, but still a messy way to do things.

The advantage would be, that you likely have less null values and therefor fewer storage-consumption. Which then again, is not much of a deal of medio-core sized tables - and often even accepted, since it makes things still easier to handle. But in the end it really depends on what you try to do with it.